# NextJS 13 app routes protected /login and /register page when logged in

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, next-auth

Hii i want to ask one question, i have problem with my nextjs 13 app routes and using next auth. When i successfully login, I can access my Login and Register page. And i want to block user when user is logged in, cannot access /login and /register page. In Login.tsx I used server components but inside the server component I used another component and then the other component use client side. Like this

/app/(auth)/login/page.tsx

```
import LoginForm from "@/components/organisms/LoginForm";

export default async function Login() {
  return (
    <section className="flex min-h-screen">
      <div className="hidden bg-primaryimage lg:block lg:w-1/2"></div>
      <LoginForm />
    </section>
  );
}
```

@/components/LoginForm.tsx

```
"use client";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  Checkbox,
  Input,
  Typography,
} from "@material-tailwind/react";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const LoginForm = () => {
  const session = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    phone: "",
    password: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session?.status === "authenticated") {
      router.push("/dashboard");
    }
  });

  const loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signIn("credentials", { ...data, redirect: false }).then((callback) => {
      if (callback?.error) {
        alert(callback.error);
      }

      if (callback?.ok && !callback?.error) {
        alert("Logged in successfully!");
      }
    });
  };

  const [isRevealed, setIsRevealed] = useState(false);

  const revealPassword = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsRevealed(!isRevealed);
  };
  return (
    <Card
      color="transparent"
      shadow={false}
      className="flex min-h-screen w-full flex-col items-center justify-center px-4 lg:w-1/2"
    >
      <Image
        src={"/logo-bengkel-sampah-warna.png"}
        alt="logo bengkel sampah"
        width={160}
        height={80}
        placeholder="empty"
      />
      <Typography variant="h4" color="blue-gray">
        Sign In
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        color="gray"
        className="mt-1 w-80 px-4 text-center font-normal sm:w-96"
      >
        Hello! Please Login First to Use Our Service
      </Typography>
      <form
        className="mb-2 mt-8 w-80 max-w-screen-lg px-4 sm:w-96"
        required
        onSubmit={loginUser}
      >
        <div className="mb-1 flex flex-col gap-6">
          <label className="-mb-3 font-bold text-blue-gray-800" htmlFor="phone">
            Phone Number
          </label>
          <Input
            id="phone"
            name="phone"
            size="lg"
            type="number"
            placeholder="08123456789"
            className=" !border-t-blue-gray-200 focus:!border-t-gray-900"
            labelProps={{
              className: "before:content-none after:content-none hidden",
            }}
            onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, phone: e.target.value })}
            required
          />
          <label
            className="-mb-3 font-bold text-blue-gray-800"
            htmlFor="password"
          >
            Password
          </label>
          <Input
            id="password"
            name="password"
            type={isRevealed === false ? "password" : "text"}
            size="lg"
            placeholder="********"
            className=" !border-t-blue-gray-200 focus:!border-t-gray-900"
            labelProps={{
              className: "before:content-none after:content-none hidden",
            }}
            onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, password: e.target.value })}
            icon={<RevealIcon onClick={revealPassword} />}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <Checkbox
          label={
            <Typography
              variant="small"
              color="gray"
              className="flex items-center font-normal"
            >
              Remember me
            </Typography>
          }
          containerProps={{ className: "-ml-2.5" }}
        />
        <Button className="mt-6 bg-bs-secondary" type="submit" fullWidth>
          Sign In
        </Button>
        <Typography
          color="gray"
          className="mt-4 text-center text-xs font-normal"
        >
          I dont have an account,
          <br />
          <Link
            href="/register"
            className="ml-1 font-medium text-gray-900 hover:underline"
          >
            Please Take Me to Register Page
          </Link>
        </Typography>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};

const RevealIcon = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button role="show-password" onClick={onClick}>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        width="16"
        height="16"
      >
        <path d="M12.0003 3C17.3924 3 21.8784 6.87976 22.8189 12C21.8784 17.1202 17.3924 21 12.0003 21C6.60812 21 2.12215 17.1202 1.18164 12C2.12215 6.87976 6.60812 3 12.0003 3ZM12.0003 19C16.2359 19 19.8603 16.052 20.7777 12C19.8603 7.94803 16.2359 5 12.0003 5C7.7646 5 4.14022 7.94803 3.22278 12C4.14022 16.052 7.7646 19 12.0003 19ZM12.0003 16.5C9.51498 16.5 7.50026 14.4853 7.50026 12C7.50026 9.51472 9.51498 7.5 12.0003 7.5C14.4855 7.5 16.5003 9.51472 16.5003 12C16.5003 14.4853 14.4855 16.5 12.0003 16.5ZM12.0003 14.5C13.381 14.5 14.5003 13.3807 14.5003 12C14.5003 10.6193 13.381 9.5 12.0003 9.5C10.6196 9.5 9.50026 10.6193 9.50026 12C9.50026 13.3807 10.6196 14.5 12.0003 14.5Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  );
};
export default LoginForm;
```

I try to check inside Login.tsx components with getServerSession is failed. Because the user can open the /login page and then a few seconds redirect to another page. I want instant like middleware in NextAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a *middleware.ts* file at the root of your application. We can create a matcher which will tell the middleware what paths to run on.

In order to stop users from navigating to the sign in/up pages once authorized we can just validate the token status and check the current path, then redirect the users away from those pages.

The middleware function will call if your authorized callback returns true. Normally the authorized callback would validate the token status and redirect non authorized users, but for this we will just return true

Hopefully this helps

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export default withAuth(
    // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
    async function middleware(req) {
        const token = await getToken({ req })
        const isAuthenticated = !!token

        const authRoutes = ["/login"]

        if (authRoutes.includes(req.nextUrl.pathname) && isAuthenticated) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', req.url))
        }
    },
    {
        callbacks: {
            authorized: () => true,
        },
    }
)

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/login', "/dashboard"],
}
```

Since we're setting the authorized callback to always return true we will want to do an additional check to protect our secure pages

```
if (!authRoutes.includes(req.nextUrl.pathname) && !isAuthenticated) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to redirect users from unwanted routes is using NextJS's middleware. You can restrict users from navigating from single/multiple routes by using middleware function. It checks users logged-in(or any other condition) state before navigating to the target route.

See details here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

** Sample **

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
}
 
// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: '/about/:path*',
}
```